# How to like a photo on instagram in C# without 403 error code

Tags: c#, https, request, instagram, bots

I am trying to build a small C# bot with .net framework 3.5 and i want to implement it in the same way as GrowBot do (a chrome extension).

Until now i was able to get the followers of a user, to get the photos of a user and now i am trying to like the photo with a post request to https://www.instagram.com/web/likes/{mediaId}/like/

The problem is that i receive a 403 error code for it.

I am looking on the requests made by GrowBot and i cannot see anything different than what i do, but still GrowBot gets 200 and i get 403.

I read in an older ticket that before this call i have to make a get request to to https://www.instagram.com/p/{mediaShortName}/ because this will change the csrftoken cookie. As i see this is not happening anymore and i have the same result even if i do this or not.

In another ticket i found that i have to add a Referer. I tried this also but the same result.

I get the same response even if i try to do the request from postman.

Comment: Hi, please note: `403` means: forbidden: I know who you are but your not allowed. Maybe the extension is using other credentials, claims or scopes to access the resource.

Comment: The extension is using the logged user for that. So there should be the same credentials. Regarding the scopes and claims, should't i see them also on the request in DevTools?

Comment: Right now instagram has cookie based authentication. Do we have claims and scopes this way?

Comment: I don 't know actually, but I do know it's a common way to get a 403. Further, I am not familiar with Instagram at all :-L

Answer (score 2):

Check out [InstaSharp](https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp). You will need to instantiate a Likes object then call .Post() passing in the mediaId. As seen [here](https://github.com/InstaSharp/InstaSharp/blob/master/src/InstaSharp/Endpoints/Likes.cs) on line 55.

Comment: Thanks, i will check this project to see if it is still working because i see the last commit was made 2 years ago. But anyway, as i see there it's the same thing what i do in my application but i don't understand why i get 403 in my case.

Comment: @XamWaZZ are you able to find to like a photo in Instagram in c# ?